# WooCommerce - Modify meta key when adding to cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce product that has a meta key of `custom_length` that is set with a value of `100`

I want to be able to modify this value when the item is added to the cart. So the product itself in WooCommerce would still have the value of `100` set, but the product in the cart would have something else, like `135`

I am  looking for a hook or filter that will let me do this modification, would the `add_to_cart` be the correct action to be focusing on?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you want to do, but seems like you are looking for `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter. It will run after you click add-to-cart button and before products being added to cart.

Here is a quick example with it's accepted variables:

```
function my_awesome_validate_add_to_cart ( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations ) {
    if ( something ){
        //do something
    }
    return $passed;//$passed is boolean. Make sure to return this. TRUE will successfully add product to cart, and FALSE will return error.

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'my_awesome_validate_add_to_cart ', 10, 5 );
```